# How do you restrict users to upload only pure html files

Tags: php, html, file-upload

how can I restrict users to upload files that are Pure HTML Only.

I'm currently creating an online editor in PHP that would produce a web page which can be printed to PDF. As such, I have some HTML files that need to be dynamically included in the web page. This is because manually adding them through the online editor would take a long time as they include a lot of content, plus they contain static data which need not be changed. Think of them as presets.

Now the problem occurs when I let the users upload their own presets. As far as I know, any file with the .html extension can hold PHP code. How can I make sure that no PHP code lies within the uploaded file? Is it even possible to escape PHP tags using PHP?

Code example:

```
//User fills the PDF editor form and submits it.
is_logged(); // Login check and setting user info variables, redirects if not logged in.

if ( !isset( $_POST['gen-page'] ) {
  custom_redirect( MAIN_PATH );
}

$content .= "<html>";
$content .= "<head>";
$content .=     "<meta charset='utf-8'>";
$content .=     "<meta name=viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>";
$content .=     "<title>"$user_name"</title>";

$content .= file_get_contents( MAIN_PATH . '/uploads/' . $user_id . '/' . $user_style . '.html' ); // Contains style details.

$content .= "</head>";
$content .= "<body>";

for ($inputs as $input) { // Inputs is an array that was posted by the user.
  $content .= "<p>" . $input . "</p>";
}

$content .= file_get_contents( MAIN_PATH . '/uploads/' . $user_id . '/' . $user_file . '.html' ); // The preset that the user has uploaded.
$content .= '</body>';

$filename = MAIN_PATH.'viewable/view-' . $user_id . '.html';
file_put_contents( $filename, $content );
custom_redirect( MAIN_PATH.'viewable/view-' . $user_id . '.html' );
```

Comment: A simple solution: read the uploaded file and search for php tag.

Comment: There is no **secure** way without inspecting the file. Relying just on an extension or mime-type is not sufficient.

Comment: _“As far as I know, any file with the .html extension can hold PHP code.”_ - so what? So could any file with the extension `.txt`, `.jpeg`, `.mp4` or `.hrstgflwrksxx`. Make sure that none of those gets _parsed_ as PHP then, via proper server configuration.

Comment: @04FS Oh! I'm fairly new to php and read somewhere that php commands are executed only on .html or .php files. Could you please point me to any resource which includes _newbie friendly_ instructions?

Comment: That would be a pretty standard default configuration, yes. By you can basically instruct your web server to send _any_ kind of files through the PHP parser. So in this case, it should probably be configured to _only_ parse it in `.php` files, and nothing else. (Unless the rest of your setup relies on parsing PHP in `.html` files already. But then you could still look into disabling it for a specific data directory, and then place the user’s uploaded files in there, or sth. like that.)

Comment: But you could also argue that explicitly checking for PHP code, and then rejecting these files, would be the safer way to go. Even if you _disabled_ parsing such files as PHP “locally” (.htaccess level or something), you might be at risk if that configuration gets overwritten or reset to “default” by accident at some point. So not having any files laying around that could _potentially_ be dangerous, is rather the safer option.